# Google Picker - Alert - You are about to send 1 item to localhost. Would you like to continue?

Tags: google-picker

[image: Google Picker alert]

I'm using Google Picker Api. Google Picker is showing properly but when I select a file (selecting a file and clicking the `Select` button or double clicking a file), I get this alert: `An embedded page at docs.google.com says You are about to send 1 item to localhost. Would you like to continue?`

I'm using Nuxt/Vue but I'm not sure it relates to that. As shown in the image, the `Alert` is really coming from the Picker API itself. I tried googling this specific Alert but I can't find anything with the same problem.

When I confirm the alert, it works, but I'm not sure if this alert is intended or not. If it is, then I think I need to leave it as it is. If it's not, please let me know how to get rid of it.

***As pointed out by @Aerials:***
Check [this](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/184573419) issue tracker and give it a star if you're having the same/related problem.

[Here's](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/184467243) another one. A possible duplicate.

Comment: Same issue here. It seems to be linked with this bug: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/177046274
Please click on the star

Comment: Same problem here, waiting google to solve it

Comment: Thanks for linking the issue tracker, I forgot to link it. I've starred it before posting this question.The alert was not mentioned there before. Looks like this alert appeared while google is fixing the problem so it's fairly new, that's why I can't find anything related to this alert.

Comment: I do not believe this is the same issue as https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/177046274. This issue is Google now displaying an alert. The issue seems to be **this one**: https://issuetracker.google.com/184573419

Comment: @Aerials Thanks for pointing out. I've updated my post.

Comment: Please share more details, like the code involved to reproduce the problem and your attempts to resolve the problem. if this is a bug in the API, you'd better post this on the responsible bugtracker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue has been reported in Google's Issue Tracker here:

> https://issuetracker.google.com/184573419

Add a "+1" next to the issue number to indicate you are affected by it too.